# Find eigenvectors of an infinite dimensional vectorspace Pn(R)?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, infinite-matrices

Define a linear operator T:Pn(R)--->Pn(R) by T(p(x))=p(x)+p(2)x.

(a) How many distinct eigenvalues does T have?

(b) What are the dimensions of their corresponding eigenspaces?

---

At first I started with writing the matrix for T in terms of the standard bases and I got a big matrix that I think it will be impossible to find its characteristic polynomial. the matrix I got is in the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJoVT.jpg

so that didn't help.
Then, I tried to use the definition of an eigenvalue. T(x)=Lambda x
so I let x= an(x^n)+.....+a0           .  with (an) doesn't equal 0 (because x has to be non zero)
then: since T(x)=lambda x
so, [an(x^n)+an(2^n)x]+.......[a0+a0(x)] = lambda an(x^n)+......lambda a0

My, intention was to cancel things out but I cannot see how this is going to work.

any suggestions on how to approach this problem?
remember that the question is How many distinct eigenvalues and what are the dimensions of their eigenspaces, so if there is way to get that without finding the eigvecs and the eigvalues then thats probably easier.
Thank you in advance!

Edit:
all of my a0's should have been a1's. because if it was a0 the dimension of the vectorspace would be n+1; however its just n

Comment: Is your vector space the polynomials of degree at most n over the real numbers?  If so the vector space you've given wouldn't be infinite dimensional since (1,x,x^2,...,x^n) forms a basis of size n+1.

Comment: yeah you are right it should've been (1,x,x^2,.....,x^n-1)

Comment: Don't know, my mathjax seems to be broken - I can't recognize the formula by their typesetting (what is index, what part of a name, what a cofactor,...). And I don't see the picture at imgur.com (???)

Comment: Try using a different browser. The formula is T(P(x))=P(x) + P(2) x

Comment: OP: I have expanded my hint a bit into a more complete answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: you should be able to show that there is a eigenspace of dimension $n$ for eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$  (think about what has to happen for $T(p(x)) = p(x)$ -- try to describe all such $p(x)$).  Then find some other eigenvector for a different eigenvalue.

Expanding to a more complete solution:

$T(p(x)) = p(x)$ if and only if $p(2) = 0$.  Notice that the polynomials $p_k(x) = x^k - 2^k$ are linearly independent for different $k$ and have $p_k(2) = 0$, so this gives us an eigenspace of dimension $n$ (since $p_k(x)$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ gives $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors) for the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$.  On the other hand, for $p(x) = x$ we have $T(p(x)) = x + 2x = 3p(x)$; this gives us an eigenspace of dimension $1$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda = 3$.  Since this exhausts the whole space ($P_n(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $n+1$) we are done, and these are the full eigenspaces.

By the way, this actually works for the infinite dimensional space of all polynomials, though one does have to check that the polynomials above in fact span the whole space rather than just relying on a dimension argument, but this isn't hard.

(Edited to reflect the clarification that $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is indeed supposed to be the polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $n$.)

Comment: Downvoter:  are you downvoting this because it's wrong, or because you don't like it for some other reason?

Comment: I don't understand how you got from P(2)=0 to that the eigenspace has a dimension of n-1. And about my comment, I might have been wrong, the question says Pn(R) which is the set of all polynomials of degree n or smaller. Can you clarify how you got that the eigenspace for eigenvalue 1 is n-1 please?

Comment: If you want all polynomials of degree at most $n$, then just add 1 to every instance of $n$ in the above (I can edit the answer to reflect that).  The observation that the dimension is $n-1$ is that the polynomials $p_k(x)$ are all linearly independent and all live in that eigenspace.  So the dimension is at least $n-1$.  It is exactly $n-1$ (not more) because we can find another eigenvector with a different eigenvalue, and the whole space has dimension $n$.

Answer (score 1):

first of all notice that {1-(1/2)x,x,x^2-2x,x^3-4x,x^4-8x,.....,x^(n-1)-2^(n-2)x} is a basis of Pn(R).
T(1-(1/2)x)=1-(1/2)x
T(x^2-2x)=x^2-2x
T(x^3-4x)=x^3-4x
.
.
.
T(x^(n-1)-2^n-2x)=x^(n-1)-2^n-2x
&
T(x)=3x
So, 1 & 3 are eigen values of T with multiplicity n-1, 1 resp.

Am I right??

Comment: One of us is misunderstanding the problem, because it looks to me like $T(1-x) = (1-x) + (1-2)x = 1-2x$, not $0$.

Comment: I think Sry is right. The transformation is : T[P(x)]= P(x) + [P(2)] [x]

Comment: If $P(x) = 1-x$ then $P(2) = -1$ and $P(x) + P(2)x = (1-x) + (-1)x = 1-2x$...

Comment: I am so sorry I meant to say that universalset is the right one.